# Average of values from an array with php

Tags: php

How from this array I can make an average ?

```
$array=Array
(
    "Element_1" => 255,
    "Element_2" => 95,
    "Element_3" => 100
);
```

I should get `150`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below code :

- [array_sum()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php) : Returns the sum of values in an array
- [count()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) : Count all elements in an array, or something in an object

**Code:**

```
<?php
$array=Array
(
    "Element_1" => 255,
    "Element_2" => 95,
    "Element_3" => 100
);
echo $average = array_sum($array) / count($array);
```

**Output:**

```
150
```

**Demo:  [Click Here](https://eval.in/805903)**

Answer (score 1):

You can [sum](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php) the values in the array and then divide them by the [count](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) of elements in the array.

```
$sum = array_sum($array); 
$count = count($array); 

echo $avg = $sum / $count;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$average = array_sum($array) / count($array);
```